# How to pass arguments to python script with non-english locale

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

**Scenario:**

- Launch remote jupyter notebook
- Build a string `string` with english and non-english(cyrillic) locale. For example, `string="this is аргумент"`
- Launch python script from jupyter cell and pass `string` as an argument:
  `!python script --arg $string`

**Problem** is in the encoding:

- The command `!python script --arg $string` itself does not start the script - just "dies" on infinite execution phase(no Exceptions and no errors. I guess, it has bash errors, which are not transmitted into jupyter, but i can not check, because not allowed to type cyrillic chars in remote console)
- First problem was solved passing encoded string instead of raw string:
  `string_encoded = string.encode(encoding='utf-8')
  !python script --arg $string_encoded`
  This works, **but requires decoding of the `string` in the `script`**, which is a struggle for me - i can't decode string representation of bytes, which looks like:
  `bthis is \xd0\xb0\xd1\x80\xd0\xb3\xd1\x83\xd0\xbc\xd0\xb5\xd0\xbd\xd1\x82`

**Context:**

- `echo $LC_CTYPE: UTF-8`
- `sys.default_encoding(): utf-8`